# Fetch offset cell from regexextract on different sheet tab if data validation equals certain value

Tags: validation, google-sheets, match, google-sheets-formula, gs-vlookup

I have searched around but can't find anything that gets me quite there. I have tried various methods but can't get it.

Sheet A - has Tab 1 and Tab 2

In Tab 1, cell O22, I have a data validation list of items. Depending on the item I pick, I want the cell below - O23 - to check a column on Tab 2 and find the phrase from cell O22.

When the phrase is matched then get an offset cell one to the left of the matched value on Tab 2 and return that result into cell O23.

This is because I am using the data validation to allow for a choice of items and ultimately return a URL which is then fed into a Google Sheets app script. I've tried using indirect, offset, address etc but I keep falling short.

Any tips would be appreciated.

EDIT: An example copy is here: *removed* - thank you.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: Hello, I cannot share the direct sheet but will make a similar copy. Will figure out how to do so.

Comment: I have added a document, please let me know if you have access issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `VLOOKUP`

```
=IFNA(VLOOKUP(O22, {Sheet2!E27:E29, Sheet2!A27:D29}, 2, 0))
```

Comment: Thank you! I was very close it seems.